# What's the proper way of binding touchstart on React JS?

Tags: javascript, touch-event, reactjs

I am learning React JS and as of now I cannot find any example on the source code, tests or on the official docs. On the docs the `touchStart` event is said to be supported but `handleTouchStart` does not work.

The only place I found and example that actually works was on [react-touch](https://github.com/petehunt/react-touch-lib/blob/90fb75f0f2bc92c4d9ac8b90806a10157aae3aa9/src/primitives/TouchableArea.js#L42-L49) project.

The following code works, but is this the only way of binding? It looks like a cheap workaround for me.

```
var MyHeader = React.createClass({
  handleTouchStart: function() {
    console.log('handleTouchStart');
  },
  render: function() {
    return this.transferPropsTo(
        <header onTouchStart={this.handleTouchStart}>{title}</header>
    );
  }
};
```

What is actually the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 26):

Since React v0.14, you don't have to call `React.initializeTouchEvents(true);` manually anymore.

http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#breaking-changes

Answer (score 9):

When playing with touch events I added `React.initializeTouchEvents(true)` to the `componentWillMount` component lifecycle method and it seemed to work correctly.

```
var MyHeader = React.createClass({
  componentWillMount: function(){
    React.initializeTouchEvents(true);
  },
  handleTouchStart: function() {
    console.log('handleTouchStart');
  },
  render: function() {
    return this.transferPropsTo(
        <header onTouchStart={this.handleTouchStart}>{title}</header>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Hy, Iraê!

You have to call React.initializeTouchEvents(true) before any rendering. Check react doc here: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#touch-events

Comment: This was not the problem. It's fixed with now and the code I posted works. I think my question was invalid. I was under the impression that `onTouchStart={this.handleTouchStart}` would be automatic, by naming convention.
Is deleting the question itself ok? I don't think it helps anyone the way it is..

Comment: As an addendum, now that React has passed v0.12, `initializeTouchEvents` has been removed and touchevents [should supposedly just work](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2468).

Comment: The link you gave for more tutorials is now broken