# What to use for onClick on mobile?

Tags: reactjs

It seems like onClick doesn't quite work with mobile, however it works fine on a desktop browser. What is the best way to do this on mobile - know when an element is pressed?

Here's how I'm using it in my return statement:

```
    ...
    return (
      <div>
        <div 
          className={"bus-route-number " + this.props.data.busNumber} 
          onClick={this.toggleShowDestination}
        >
          <h1>{this.props.data.busNumber}</h1>
          <h4>{this.props.data.fullRoute}</h4>
        </div>
        {destinations}
      </div>
    )
    ...
```

Comment: For mobile, you should try `Touch Event`, `onTouchEnd` is the good one for replacing `onClick`.

Comment: You might add this also;  

  React.initializeTouchEvents(true)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to use touch events. In order to enable touch events, you will have to run the following before rendering any component.

```
React.initializeTouchEvents(true)
```

More information [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#touch-events). There are similar questions on SO asking the same question - one of them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059151/whats-the-proper-way-of-binding-touchstart-on-react-js) shows an example usage.