# React onTouchStart not firing

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement a swipe feature in ReactJS, but before I even really dive in, I cannot seem to get the onTouchStart event listener to work. I have looked online but most answers are outdated, or do not address my question directly. This link is where I got the most information thus far, but it still falls short of my question and some of the answers are outdated. [What's the proper way of binding touchstart on React JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059151/whats-the-proper-way-of-binding-touchstart-on-react-js)

I went down to creating the simplest form of the functionality and included that code below. I was trying to console.log when `onTouchStart={this.swiped}>` occurs. On a side note, if I change the listener to onClick `onClick={this.swiped}>`, this works immediately.

```
class App extends React.Component {
   contructor() {
    super();
    this.swiped = this.swiped.bind(this);
   }

  swiped() {
    console.log("Swiped")    
  }

  render() {
    return (
     <div>
      <div 
      className='swipe-card'
      onTouchStart={this.swiped}>Swipe Me
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Also, I have added the CSS style `cursor: pointer` to the element. I also tried adding

```
componentWillMount: function(){
  React.initializeTouchEvents(true);
}
```

But according to the React blogs, React.initializeTouchEvents is no longer required.

This seems so trivial and something that should be really simple to implement. What am I missing? My goal is to implement this without an external library. Here is a link to Codepen where I was trying to implement this. 
https://codepen.io/jorgeh84/pen/mMdBZg

Answer (score 3):

This works for me. Maybe the issue is that you're not testing it on a real device?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  contructor() {
    super();
  }

  swiped = () => {
    console.log("Swiped")    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='swipe-card' onTouchStart={this.swiped}>Swipe Me</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('App'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that Daniel was onto something. So I do not need to be testing on an actual device, however, when using Chrome, you will need to use their device toolbar to simulate a mobile device for this to work.